# how to post value in php one to other page using ahref tag in php html

Tags: php, html, mysql

In this code:

```
<td align="left"><a href="update.php?id='.$od_id.'">' ."Complete" . '</td></tr>';
```

I generate multiple `od_id` so when I click on other particular `od_id` this `od_id` post by other page but this `od_id`. I don't want to display on display "Complete"  only and on that behalf I can access this `od_id` in multiple pages but I am trying to use hidden type but it not working so any other process to post this value other page.

It is possible to send this so please help me.

One more thing, I am using hidden type but is not working. Also, how it's work for post the value from one page to other page using html in php tag.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);

echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%" border="1">
     <tr>
     <td align="left"><b>Order Details Number</b></td>
     <td align="left"><b>Menu Id</b></td>
     <td align="left"><b>SubMenu Id</b></td>
     <td align="left"><b>Quantity</b></td>
     <td align="left"><b>Note</b></td>
     <td align="left"><b>Note Master</b></td>
     <td align="left"><b>Status</b></td>
     </tr> ';
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {

         $od_id = $row['od_id'];

        echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
     <td align="left">' .$row['od_id'] .'</a></td>
     <td align="left">' . $row['menu_id'] . '</td>
     <td align="left">' . $row['submenu_id'] . '</td>
     <td align="left">' .$row['quantity'] . '</td>
     <td align="left">' .$row['note'] . '</td>
     <td align="left">' .$row['note_master'] . '</td>
     <td align="left"><a href="update.php?id='.$od_id.'">' ."Complete" . '</td>
     </tr>';
        $i++;
        }

 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Is variable `id` will carry the whole `od_id` generated value? It must be an array

Comment: There is a huge knowledge gap present, you should research more about POST and GET HTTP methods, about what <a> element is, what form elements are and how they are transmitted via POST or GET method. Your question as it is now makes 0 sense and there's no way you can get an explanation, unless you copy-paste the answer. Hopefully, no one will give you the code that you'll copy paste, you should **learn** these things.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use mysql_* functions they are depracated.
2. Yes it is possible via html just use `<form action="yoururl.html" method="POST"></form>`
3. If you want **POST** values from PHP to another site you should use **CURL** http://coderscult.com/how-to-post-data-with-curl-in-php/
4. But if it is within your site just use **$_SESSION**.
5. If you want to use **$_GET** instead of post on update.php use should use code `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];`
   to get variable from **GET**
6. If you have form on generated page by php which is going to be submited you can use `<input type="hidden" />` to send variable to other page.
7. If you want to hide **od_id** in link you can encrypt it with [mcrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)
8. You use **while()** loop in the same way you could use **for()** loop. `for($i=0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($res); ++$i)` does exactly the same.

Last thing is that you should replace

```
   <td align="left"><a href="update.php?id='.$od_id.'">' ."Complete" . '</td>
```

with

```
  <td align="left"><a href="update.php?id='.$row['od_id'].'">' ."Complete" . '</td>
```

and remove `$od_id = $row['od_id'];` it doesn't look like you needed assign new variable. Did you?

Comment: Please don't tell people not to use mysql_* functions when you don't know if they have a choice / you can't suggest how they work around non-availabiltiy of alternatives.

Comment: There is always a choice to use pdo, mysqli etc. Why shouldn't I advice them not to use functions that will be removed in future and don't use a lot of functions from MYSQL db engine?

Comment: @symcbean - what load of nonsense, people should be told to use PDO and not to use mysql_*, we'd have less cabbage code and less "legacy" to support. And if one can't use PDO because of [insert reason], you can bet that there is no actual reason behind it except obsolete server software and as usual - people with 0 clue working the job they shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @N.B.: please read my comment again. I agree people should be told to use non-depercated functions - but it serves no useful purpose unless you can show them how to avoid using those APIs. How do you know what version of PHP is installed on Samdip's server? What extensions? If he has any control over it's config? Did you explain how to reconfigure the server? Did you provide a URL for the shims available? Did you explain how to convert his existing codebase which might represent millions of man-hours of work?

Comment: further not using deprecated APIs should be a comment - it's not an answer Sandip's problem.

Comment: It is one of suggestions answer is given in the rest of points. Is it forbideen to give some clues to users about what they do wrong?

Comment: @symcbean - I'm sorry but what's the point of your comment? The person asking the question is clearly a newbie, he doesn't even know about what form elements are, I sincerely doubt there's any point recycling what's being said on SO 100 times a day. Plus the answer contains relevant information. So yes, people should be **told** to use PDO, and if they run obsolete software - well, they should pay the price for it, namely: not receiving answers how to implement garbage to compliment the rubbish in the first place.

Comment: What's sense of posting comment if I mentioned it in my answer? I didn't write just about mysql that is depracated but I've attached a lot of solutions that he may use.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the closing "a" tag in the wrong place. If you look at the while loop, the first "td" line has a closing "a" tag. That tag looks like it should be on the line of the last "td" where you have an opening "a" tag **without** a closing tag. You also do not seem to have any need to be concatenating the word "Complete". It looks like it should just be a part of the echoed string.

Also, from what I can see, you can clean up your code by removing the unnecessary concatenations. Any variable in PHP that is placed within a double quote does not need to be concatenated. You can simply use, for example:

```
echo "<td align='left'>$row[quantity]</td>";
```

If you are using a decent IDE then it will show up in a color coded fashion which is useful for readability.